# use multiple id_rsa files (SSH-KEYGEN) to push on github

Tags: git, github, private-key, git-clone, ssh-keygen

I am using the following command to generate SSH-Keygen on my MAC

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "<myemail to github>"
```

I want to create two SSH-keygen for my two GitHub accounts and then use them separately pushing to individual GitHub account. But when I create SSH-keygen file by default id_rsa file is used to login which allows only one git account to connect.

Please help me that how I can provide the correct SSH-keygen file while pushing the code to the GitHub repository.

Comment: Are you specifying different filenames each time you run `ssh-keygen` "?

Comment: Yes when it ask the filename then I am specifying different filenames but not sure how can i use that file while login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume your home directory is `/home/userName` and your ssh keys are stored in the `.ssh` subdirectory (the default location on Linux).
First, generate SSH keys with different names:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_1
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

That will create the following key files:

```
/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_1
/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_1.pub
/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_2
/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_2.pub
```

Let's also assume that **id_rsa_1** is intended for use with a GitHub account called *user_1*, and that **id_rsa_2** will be used for *user_2*.

Steps:

1. Copy the contents of the `.pub` files to the respective accounts in GitHub:
   **Settings** -> **SSH Keys** -> **New SSH Key** -> paste key in the text box
2. Edit (or create if it doesn't exist) the file `/home/userName/.ssh/config`. We're going to assign separate aliases for each GitHub account, and map them to *github.com*. We'll call the aliases **host_1** and **host_2**. The `config` file should look like this:

```
Host host_1.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_1
Host host_2.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    Port 22
    IdentityFile /home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

3. Now we can clone the repositories using the aliases assigned in the `config` file. If there is a repo called *repo_1* under account *user_1*, it can be cloned using this command:

```
git clone git@host_1.github.com:user_1/repo_1
```

Similarly, for *repo_2* under *user_2*:

```
git clone git@host_2.github.com:user_2/repo_2
```

Hopefully it's clear what is happening: running `git` commands on a remote **host_N.github.com** with the `ssh` syntax tells git to use SSH as its transport. When SSH finds the DNS name for the remote in the config file, it discovers that it should actually connect to **github.com** and to use the key `/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa_N` to authenticate.