# Create multiple EdDSA SSH keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I've read a bunch on how to do using rsa. Now, how can I create multiple ssh keys using EdDSA i.e. `id_ed25519`

- I can't add the same existing key to multiple github accounts I own (key already in use)
- While attempting to create a second key, I'm unable to write a custom name (like one does when using rsa) inside the script

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519_customname -C "myemail@gmail.com"`

[docs don't cover that either](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

How can I create multiple EdDSA SSH keys?

Comment: Can you be more clear about the problem? Running that command works just fine (the argument to `-C` is appended to the public key as expected).

Comment: the issue isn't the command. That command was used when creating the first key. To create a second one I'd need to modify the file name with a custom name. Which is the heart of the issue

Comment: This is the docs: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen . What you need is the first syntax: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/ed25519_customname -C "myemail@gmail.com"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62973365/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh-keygen%5D+different+name

Comment: thanks @phd I'll spend sometime reading those docs and learning more about those flags

Answer (score 1):

Do not specify the custom name under the -t tag.

Simply run `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` Then, you will be prompted to enter the file path. The default, of course, is `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`.

Instead, enter the path with your custom file name, for example `~/.ssh/my_custom_id_ed25519`.

Now, you will have another key created and can be added to another GitHub account.